# Bricked Netduino 3 WIFI & Netduino Plus 2

Tags: c#, netduino

I hope someone here can help me. I've managed to brick two Netduinos today. It happens when I run the following code: http://pastebin.com/DjUbM3hN

I found the code example [here](https://netmftoolbox.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Toolbox.NETMF.Hardware.HBridge) and from what people say, it should be working just fine. I don't know if my hardware setup can have caused any issues?

But the problem is, when I run the code, then Visual Studio isnt able to find the debugger engine, and after that I cant do anything on either device. I've tried to ping it with MFDeploy, but no luck there either. I am really unsure what happened and what to do from here.

Let me know if anymore details are needed in order to help me. Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution here. Really easy. Takes about 2 minutes to reset it with this guide: http://forums.netduino.com/index.php?/topic/11842-how-to-recover-non-responding-netduino-3/#entry62928